# Using addVars in Gurobi with tuple as indinces

Tags: python-3.x, variables, tuples, gurobi

I am pretty new to modeling with Gurobi/python interface.I want to create some variables with two indinces like x[k,i],while k and i are tuple and  like this sets

```
arcs1 = [('G1', 'source', 'node1'), ('G2', 'source', 'node2')]   #list， with the elements consist of a single tuple
arcs2 = [(('G3', 'node1', 'node3'), ('G4', 'node2', 'node5')), (('G5', 'node1', 'node6'), ('G7', 'node4', 'node5'))]    #a list of tuples of tuples                                         
EK, EA = tuplelist(arcs1), tuplelist(arcs2)
```

what confuses me is that, if I use addVars to create variables with EK and EA,
`x = m.addVars(EK, EA, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="x")`

the key of variables I got would be like

`('G1', 'source', 'node1', ('G3', 'node1', 'node3'), ('G4', 'node2', 'node5'))`

instead of

`(('G1', 'source', 'node1'), ('G3', 'node1', 'node3'), ('G4', 'node2', 'node5'))`

And when I set objective or constraints like the part I sharing,

```
m.setObjective((quicksum(x[k,i] for k in EK for i in EA)), name="obj1")
```

I got a Keyerror says
"Keyerror:(('G1', 'source', 'node1'), ('G3', 'node1', 'node3'), ('G4', 'node2', 'node5'))"
what should I do to make sure the form of variables I created would be the second one?  thx for help

Comment: Do you mean for arcs1 to be a list of tuples while arcs2 is a list of tuples of tuples?

Comment: yes，thats what I mean,@Greg Glockner. sry for me a fresh to stack overflow that I dont know how to answear your comment, so I have to text in a new comment here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Especially if you are just starting to learn how to use gurobipy to model your problems, I recommend using simpler data structures instead of nested tuples and lists. In general, you should not mix different data types in the same list. While it's possible in Python, you are almost guaranteed to run into issues at some point.

Maybe this tutorial is helpful to get started: https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/quickstart_linux/cs_python_dictionary_examp.html#subsection:pythondictionary